importing CSV data with multiline cells into R
I have a CSV dataset where some cells contain multiline text separated by "enters". When I try to import it into R, I'm facing an issue where only the first line of the multiline text is imported, and the rest gets truncated.
For example, in the CSV file, the data might look like this:
166559;26723;"Pauta: 
•blablablablbala
blabalabalbalbalabalba

yayadayayayaya
";

Var1           Var2      Var3
166559        26723      Pauta

As you can see, I lose the rest of the information in Var3, which is crucial for my analysis. This issue occurs in several columns of the dataset, and due to the large number of lines and lack of a consistent pattern, manual correction or simple routines are not feasible options.
Could someone please provide guidance on how to import this data correctly into R and how to correct this issue?
